# Image in UITableViewCell of flexible height

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

I have a table view cell of variable height.How can I place an image at the middle (vertically) of the table cell ? Is there any way to set from IB ? or can i do it in codes ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation on `UITableViewCell`.  You can directly set the image in the following way:

```
[[myTableViewCell imageView] setImage: myImage];
```

if you're using iPhone SDK 3.0.  If you're writing for 2.0, you need to use:

```
[myTableViewCell setImage: myImage];
```

but this is deprecated in 3.0.